# Como romper el bucle while

Tags: python

Hola tengo este codigo y la funcion es que si pones un codigo que esta en la lista te vuelva a pedir que pongas otro codigo pero si no esta en esa lista que salga del bucle, cosa que a mi no me funciona. Como hago para que cuando pongas un codigo que ya existe, se pare el programa?

```
inicio=True

while inicio:
        s1ql="select codigo from jugadores"
        mycursor.execute(s1ql)
        codigos = mycursor.fetchall()
        codigos2 = []
        for codigo in codigos:
            codigos2.append(codigo[0])
        while True:
            codigo = int(input("Código del jugador: "))
            if(codigo in codigos2):
                print("El código no está disponible")
            else:
                break
```

Comment: ¿Y cuándo hacés que _inicio_ sea `False`?

Comment: No entiendo lo que quieres decir.

Comment: La primera línea es `inicio=True`, la segunda `while inicio`.

Comment: ¿Eres consciente que tienes 2 ciclos infinitos anidados? No es que eso esté mal, si no que como tienes tu lógica, si logras romper el `while` más interno, el primero volverá meterte al bucle, no pudiendo salir nunca de ahí.

Comment: Gracias‍♂️‍♂️‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

**Análisis**

El `while inicio:` no tiene sentido, pues dentro del bloque la variable `inicio` nunca cambia. Por otra parte, tampoco tiene sentido volver a leer una y otra vez la base de datos, pues tampoco cambia dentro del bloque y debe ser grande.

Leer la base de datos completa para validar el código de un jugador no tiene sentido; lo correcto es pedir el código y luego verificar si ese jugador existe en la base de datos.

En este ejemplo tenemos una base "jugadores.db", con una tabla "jugadores" donde se registran (codigo, nombre) del jugador.

Una vez ingresado el código a buscar, hacemos un `select` condicional (`where codigo = {buscar}`). Como el código es Primary Key, debería retorna sólo el mismo código (si el jugador existe), o `None`, si no se encontró ninguno.

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("jugadores.db")

while True:
    buscar = int(input("Código del jugador: "))
    cursor = conn.execute(f"SELECT codigo from jugadores where codigo = {buscar}")
    if cursor.fetchone():
        print("El código no está disponible")
    else:
        break
```